# Select from the same table and display in rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table that contains various list items

```
*LIST_ITEMS*
 ID
 LIST_ID_FK
 DESCRIPTION
 VALUE_ID_FK
```

I need to select all of the DESCRIPTION's where the LIST_ID_FK'S THAT EQUAL 1 and all of the DESCRIPTIONS where the LIST_ID_FK = 2 and all DESCRIPTION'S where the LIST_ID_FK = 3

```
 LIST_ID_FK value 1's have no VALUE_ID_FK
 LIST_ID_FK value 2's have the FK of value 1 in the VALUE_ID_FK column
 LIST_ID_FK value 3's have the FK of value 2 in the VALUE_ID_FK column
```

The output should be this:

```
List1    List2      List3
England  Liverpool  test3
England  London     test1
England  London     test2
England  London     test3
```

The problem I am getting is trying to get everything out of the same table and linked to each other to make up the rows.
Is this possible to do?

Comment: I puzzled over this for a while, but the problem description is unclear.  What do `England, Liverpool, and test3` have in common?  Perhaps if you showed the input data that would be used to produce the output you listed, it might be possible to infer their relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the `list_ID_FK` to the word test

```
SELECT Description, 'test' || list_ID_FK List3
FROM mytable
WHERE list_ID_FK IN (1,2,3)
```

Or you can use a UNION. The first option is almost definitely faster

```
SELECT Description, test1 List3
FROM mytable
WHERE list_ID_FK = 1
UNION
SELECT Description, test2 List3
FROM mytable
WHERE list_ID_FK = 2
UNION
SELECT Description, test3 List3
FROM mytable
WHERE list_ID_FK = 3
```